# How can I install the OpenGL libraries in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: sony, vaio, opengl

I need OpenGL for some processing programming, how can I install the OpenGL libraries in Ubuntu 11.04?

I have a Sony Vaio F series with nVIDIA drivers installed.

Answer (score 1):

You should have OpenGL runtime support already. You can check that using `glxinfo` in a terminal.

If you are looking for the development headers, you would need to install `libgl1-mesa-dev`. Extra packages might be necessary depending on your programming language.